# array to xml conversion error in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays

This is my code,

```
 $row=array(username=>'username',password=>'password');
 $var=array_flip($row);
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
 array_walk_recursive($var, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
 $result= $xml->asXML();
```

If username and password are different say 'abcd' & 'efgh' respectively, xml looks like this:

```
<root>
<username>abcd</username>
<password>efgh</password>
</root>
```

but if they are same say 'abcd', xml looks like this:

```
<root>
<password>abcd</password>
</root>
```

and I want that it should show like

```
<root>
<username>abcd</username>
<password>abcd</password>
</root>
```

So how can I solve that?

Comment: if you see the xml generated, when username and password are same <username> node is not created in xml. How to solve that?

Comment: When you do array_flip duplicate keys are discarded.

Comment: but without array_flip() the xml will be like this <abcd>username</abcd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
array_walk_recursive($row, function ($value, $key) use ($xml) { 
    $xml->addChild($key, $value); 
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php
>
> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and
> all others will be lost.

if password equals to username, then array_flip returns array with just one element

```
array_flip(array(username=>'abcd',password=>'abcd'))
// will return array('abcd'=>'password')
```

you cat use foreach instead of array_walk_recursive in this case

```
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
   $xml->addChild($k, $v);
```